# Checking multiple values for a variable

Tags: python, variables

```
original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower()
    first = str(word)[0]
    print first
    if str(first) == "a" or "e" or "i" or "u" or "o":
        print "vowel"
else:
    print "consonant"
```

I want to check if a word starts with a vowel or consonant. However, this part does not work: if `str(first) == "a" or "e" or "i" or "u" or "o"`

So how would you check if the first letter is either "a" or "e" or "i" or "u" or "o"?

Answer (score 17):

Use `in`

```
if len(original) and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    print first
    if first in ('a','e','i','o','u'):
        print "vowel"
    else:
        print "consonant"
```

If you were trying to use OR clause you must use like this BUT it's not the better pythonic way:

```
if first =='a' or first =='e' or first =='i' or first =='o' or first =='u':
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if str(first) == "a" or "e" or "i" or "u" or "o":
```

should moditied to

```
if str(first) in ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"):
```

Python has a explicit demand on indent. Make sure you have a right indent.

```
original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower()
    first = str(word)[0]
    print first
    if str(first) in ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"):
        print "vowel"
    else:
        print "consonant"
```