# Getting a Colon Syntax Error in Python

Tags: python, syntax-error

Input

```
yourChoice = True

while yourChoice:
    inf_or_ltd = input('Would you like to play infinte or a limited game?: '):
        if inf_or_ltd = ((('Limited') or ('limited')) and (compScore == ('3'))):
            exit = True
            print("You lost, Goodbye")
            break
            time.sleep(1)
```

Why is the colon a invalid syntax? I've checked the bracket balance and the previous lines (which are just variables and importing a few modules). It says that `a limited game?: '):` is invalid syntax.

Comment: `input(..):`, why do you write a colon after `input`? Furthermore note https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851146/checking-multiple-values-for-a-variable

Comment: You wouldn't write `a = 2:`, would you? See also. https://stackoverflow.com/q/215581/8881141

Comment: Oh, it was the two mistakes you guys mentioned. It was some small mistake, like I thought it would be. Anyway, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, a colon `:` defines the start of a scope block, it's essentially the same as `{` in most languages.
But the colon isn't enough, scope blocks also need to be idented. The amount of identation depends on the parent block.

```
scope1:
    scope2:
        scope3:
```

A block ends when its identation ends, i.e.:

```
scope1:
    scope1_statement
    scope2:
        scope3:
            scope3_statement
        scope2_statement
    scope1_statement
```

Now, when would you create a new scope block? Well, you create them when you need to define a new scope, such as:

- Declaring new methods (`def`, `lambda`, ...)
- Declaring new code branches (`if` conditions, `try-catch`...)

In your scenario, you are trying to create a new scope after a statement (an instruction) which in this case is an *assignment* `inf_or_ltd = input('...')`.

Python instructions cannot create a new scope block.

You need to place your `if` on the same identation as the above assignment;

```
inf_or_ltd = input('...')
if inf_or_ltd == anything:
     # do something
else:
     # do something else
```