# I've created variables but none of them are working

Tags: python

So basically I've been creating a little narrative choice game in python and it has plenty of choices so it has a lot of if this else that but im confused on why they are not working
I've tried to move stuff and to no prevail

```py
print("On the large worktop you see a pot filled with a stew it seems rather fresh")
answer2=input("do you eat it?")
if answer2=="yes" or "Yes" or " yes":
    print("The salty taste of the stew makes you splutter but fills your stomach,You gain 3 hp")
else:
    print("Out of caution you leave the stew on the work top")
answer3=input("As you leave the kitchen the tunnel splits into two do you go right or left?")
if answer3=="left" or "Left":
    print("you head down the left route you hear a slow click spikes rise from the ground and impale your foot you loose 3 hp and slowly limp back to the to the start of the passage and make your way down the right side")
else:
    print("you walk down to the end of the passage way")
```

Comment: You want to format your question properly

Comment: You need to change `if answer2=="yes"or"Yes"or" yes":` to `if answer2=="yes" or answer2=="Yes" or answer2==" yes":`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking multiple values for a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851146/checking-multiple-values-for-a-variable)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 2):

Your if statements are problematic in that they are incomplete. Each **or** that you want to consider must be a full logical expression.

```
if answer2 == "yes" or answer2 == "Yes" or answer2 == " yes":

if answer3 == "left" or answer3 == "Left":
```

Answer (score 1):

Recipes given but I wanted to elaborate just a little bit:

`if x == "yes" or " yes "` will always return `True` because the `or " yes "` is basically asking python if `" yes "` is `None`. And it's not `None`, because it's `yes`.

As mentioned above, you want to change this to something like:

```
if answer == "Yes" or answer == " Yes ":
    ...
```

I would actually recommend taking this little further:

```
if "yes" in answer.lower():
   ...
```

This way you check if yes is in the answer (obviously this has downsides to make sure you don't use `yes` in the other questions) but helps your code be little more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

When using relational operators in python, make sure that operands are present on both left and right side of the operator when using it with `and`  & `or`.

Doing something like `if answer2=="yes" or "Yes" or " yes":`, will always execute the statements present inside the `if` block, as this will always evaluate to `true`. Hence, when the user enters the value of `answer2` something other than 'Yes' or 'yes', the  statements present inside the if statement will not be executed.

```
print("On the large worktop you see a pot filled with a stew it seems rather fresh")
answer2=input("do you eat it?")
if answer2 == "yes" or answer2 == "Yes":
    print("The salty taste of the stew makes you splutter but fills your stomach,You gain 3 hp")
else:
    print("Out of caution you leave the stew on the work top")
answer3=input("As you leave the kitchen the tunnel splits into two do you go right or left?")
if answer3 == "left" or answer3 == "Left":
    print("you head down the left route you hear a slow click spikes rise from the ground and impale your foot you loose 3 hp and slowly limp back to the to the start of the passage and make your way down the right side")
else:
    print("you walk down to the end of the passage way")
```