# Python substring in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose this code

```
x = "boo"
if "a" or "z" in x:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

returns True.

But why?
I expected it to return False, becuause neither a nor z is in x.
Do I misunderstand `in`?

I frequently use `in` to see if a string contains a single substring. E.g.

```
x = "eggs and spam"
if "spam" in x:
    return "add sausage"
```

Comment: voted to reopen as [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851146/checking-multiple-values-for-a-variable) offers no explanation why this does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `"a" or "z" in x` is evaluated as `"a" or ("z" in x)` (see [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) to understand why)
- `"z" in x` is `False` for `x = "boo"`
- `"a" or False` is `True` (as `"a"` is a non-empty string; `bool("a") = True`).

what you mean to do is this:

```
if "a" in x or "z" in x:
    ...
```

if you are comfortable working with [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)s you could also try this:

```
if set("az") & set(x):
    ...
```